# Multiples filtros en una consulta a base de datos desde Laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Cuando ejecuto la sentencia SQL

```
SELECT * FROM `payments` WHERE `estado` IN ('abono', 'adeudo', 'espera') AND `fecha_pago` < '2016-09-08' ORDER BY `id`
```

Resultado: me trae los datos correctamente,

Pregunta: Cual es la forma, para hacer lo mismo en laravel? he intentado hacer cosas como esta y nada.

```
return $query->where('estado', 'IN', ['abono','adeudo','espera'])->where('fecha_pago','<','2016-09-08');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aunque tu respuesta es correcta, en teoría y dependiendo como lo manejes te falta el método get(), y las comillas dobles que utilizas no son necesarias en la variable de la fecha y según tu query inicial te falta el orderBy.

También, para respetar PSR-2, debes insertar un espacio después de cada argumento que pasas.

Asumo que esto lo estás insertando en otro query (sería un subquery) o algo así.

```
return $query->where('fecha_pago', '<', $var)
    ->whereIn('estado', ['abono', 'adeudo', 'espera'])
    ->orderBy('id');
```

---

Para referencia futura de otras personas que entren a esta pregunta, voy a responder a la pregunta de una forma más neutra:

Normalmente podrías tener un modelo que se llame Payment, que extiende a Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model y que utiliza la tabla payments, y el query se haría de la siguiente manera:

```
$resultado = Payment::where('fecha_pago', '<', '2016-09-08')
                 ->whereIn('estado', ['abono', 'adeudo', 'espera'])
                 ->orderBy('id')
                 ->get();
```

Ahora, si no se desea o no hay un modelo atado a la tabla ni una relación, o si simplmente se quiere hacer sin modelo, sería de esta manera:

```
$resultado = DB::table('payments')
                 ->where('fecha_pago', '<', '2016-09-08')
                 ->whereIn('estado', ['abono', 'adeudo', 'espera'])
                 ->orderBy('id')
                 ->get();
```

Incluso se puede hacer con inyección de dependencias, pero eso ya es una implementación más avanzada.

Comment: Efectivamente, mi consulta lo hago desde un scope y después en el controlador lo ordeno (->orderBy('id')). Y también modifique las comillas, aparte estoy ordenando lo más que puedo con los consejos que me das del PSR-2. Como no trabajo de esto y lo estoy aprendiendo empíricamente. Gracias.-

Answer (score 0):

```
return $query->where('fecha_pago', '<', "$var")->whereIn('estado', ['abono','adeudo','espera']);
```

lo solucione asi, si hay sugerencias mejor. son bienvenidas.